# # [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1598N An attempt to connect to the database server failed because of a licensing problem. SQLSTATE=42968 SQLCODE=-1598

Tags: python, java, python-3.x, db2

**[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1598N  An attempt to connect to the database server failed because of a licensing problem.  SQLSTATE=42968  SQLCODE=-1598**

My requirement is to connect the db2 database using python, so in python there we have ibm_db package, using that we can make connection to the db2 database.

i have installed the ibm_db package though pip command

**# pip install ibm_d2**

while making connection to db2  by using ibm_db.connect method. getting the below error.

**# [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1598N  An attempt to connect to the database server failed because of a licensing problem.  SQLSTATE=42968  SQLCODE=-1598**

This error is causing due to missing of license files, what type of license files have to provide and license files name and where to place.

please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means you are in for a painful learning [*experience*](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sql1598n-error-connecting-mainframe-db2-ibm-data-server-driver-even-though-db2-connect-license-file-exists-license-directory-install-path).

Answer (score 0):

This is frequently asked. Did you do any research before asking?

You always need to know the Db2-server **platform** and **version** when asking for help with Db2 because these determine the answer. You should write these details in your question and use correct stackoverflow tags per platform.

When accessing Db2-LUW servers (linux, unix, windows, cloud), it is **free** in the sense that there is no licence file required at the workstation where you run python.

But to access either Db2-for-Z/OS,  or Db2-for-i-series , via ODBC (i.e. from python) with IBM supplied drivers, it is **not free**. A licence is required, typically the "Db2 connect personal edition" licence, although it is also possible for larger corporations to deploy server-side licensing, and/or use a Db2-connect-gateway product ($$$) to avoid workstation side licensing.

This is all described in the documentation, and you can get your licence file by contacting your IBM salesperson or the person who handles such matters for your company.

For python ibm_db it is also described in detail [here](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb#-license-requirements-for-connecting-to-databases)